# FastReport demo for asp.NET MVC C# fails to work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fastreport

FastReport released a new version that supports wokring in MVC razor views.

I got the demo from their site and thought I'll give it a try. But I can not get the demo application to work. Also tried creating a new project following these steps:

fast-report.com/en/blog/37/show/

Am I missing something? The webforms demo is working perfectly..

Error I'm getting:

> 'FastReport.Web.WebReport' does not contain a definition for 'GetHtml'

Also these are not recognized in _Layout.cshtml:

```
@WebReportGlobals.Scripts()
@WebReportGlobals.Styles()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalled, reinstalled, rebooted, started the demo (thats recognize as VS2010 on my machine) by opening it from VS2012. Added missing DLL's via NuGet for MVC4 support, copied FastReport DLL's to bin directory and got it running!

[image: WebReportGlobals is still missing]

WebReportGlobals are still flagged as missing. Anyways it works!